# Avoiding getters and using DTOs for the retrieval of information when using DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, dto

[Greg Young talks](http://www.infoq.com/interviews/greg-young-ddd) about avoiding getters and setters on domain objects when using Domain Driven Design. For the use case where I want information from a persistent store to be rendered to the screen, what would the object model look like when following this architectural pattern?

Would I expect to see a DTO being retrieved directly from a repository, or perhaps an independent DtoService, supplying the Dto instances directly to the "UI layer" (say a controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at CQRS; notion would be that you would return a view specific DTO either from a reporting service or reporting view specific datastore